# Learn C++ when mastering VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net

I consider myself a master at vb.net, and now I'd like to learn C++. I know they are similar in many ways, so instead of starting from a standard "learn C++ Basics" which there are thousands of, and then move on from there on, as I have done with all other languages. I would love if someone could point me to a tutorial that learns, someone with knowledge in vb.net,  C++. Or maybe a page pointing out the differences between the two.

Also, with them being similar, is their simple converter, that can convert code on line-base from vb.net to C++? I would like to convert my current asp.net website (less than 30 lines of code right now) project to C++, as I find the best way to learn is through doing it.

Comment: "*I know they are similar in many ways*" Thinking that is probably the worst mistake you can make.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of C#? VB.Net and C# are similar in many ways, but I would say C++ is a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: Are you seriously want to go from VB.NET to C++? Didn't you mean C# instead of C++? That would be the easiest thing to do, and the smartest (in my opinion)

Comment: I would say that C++ and VB are similar in no ways at all...

Comment: If you've got 24h to spare...
http://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-Hours-2nd/dp/0672315165

Answer (score 5):

As @ildjarn and @GregHewgill pointed out, C++ is quite different from vb.net. C# and (to some extent) C++/CLI would be much closer (and despite the name, C++/CLI is *not* C++).

C++ (by itself) does essentially nothing to support web development, so converting an asp.net web site to C++ will most likely be a decidedly non-trivial exercise. There are frameworks (e.g., [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html)) that support network and web development in C++, but I don't believe they have automated tools to convert from asp.net. In any case, converting a web site to C++ using one of these libraries is *not* going to teach you much about C++. At best, it's going to teach you about that library.

I feel obliged to point out, however, that if web development is your primary interest, C++ probably isn't your best possible choice. At the very least it's quite an unpopular choice for that purpose.

The typical answer for people who already know how to program in some other language and want to learn C++ is [*Accelerated C++*](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/) (but you may want to see [The Definitive C++ Book List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for other possibilities).